# Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [data-table] component, when trying to send closure to livewire component

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, closures, laravel-livewire

I tried to send some closure to the livewire component inside a nested array but it produce this error:

> Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [data-table] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.**

What I sent to the component :

```
<livewire:data-table
    :model="$modelClass"
    :custom="[
        [
            'label' => 'E-Mail',
            'column'=> 'email'
        ],
    ]"
    :exclude="['password', 'email_verified_at', 'remember_token', 'updated_at']"
    :include="[
        [
            'label' => 'Role',
            'column'=> 'role.name',
            'format'=> fn($value, $row) => '<strong>'.ucwords($value).'</strong>',
            'formatType' => 'html'
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Search Engine',
            'links' => [
                [
                    'title' => fn($row) => $row->name.' Google',
                    'link'  => fn($row) => 'https://google.com/search?q='.$row->name,
                    'type'  => 'button',
                ]
            ],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Social Media',
            'links' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Facebook',
                    'link'  => 'https://facebook.com',
                    'type'  => 'link'
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'Instagram',
                    'link'  => 'https://instagram.com',
                    'type'  => 'link'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Email Provider',
            'links' => [
                [
                    'title' => function($row){
                        if(str_contains($row->email, 'gmail')){
                            return 'Google';
                        }elseif(str_contains($row->email, 'yahoo')){
                            return 'Yahoo';
                        }else{
                            return 'Unidentified';
                        }
                    },
                    'class' => 'cursor-pointer',
                    'onclick'  => 'return false',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]"
/>
```

Then i check in ComponentCheckshumManager class, my array that contains the closure become empty when go through Hashing using json_encode.

Before Hashing :
[Data before hashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgzqO.png)

After Hashing :
[Data after hashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btbYL.png)

This error happens only when refreshing the component, is there any correct way to send closure to the livewire component? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on `name`. If it's an attribute, then issue is somewhere else, if it's a magic function, then you have a problem. Each time a template modifies original data, you will get corrupt data. Even if it's `$user->full_name` magic function, it will corrupt original data.

Comment: I dont fully understand but i think it's an attribute. The error happen only in `:include` attribute. In the livewire component, the parameter received using public property and when component refreshed the error above happen. But when i use protected property and mount function to receive the parameter, the error above did'nt happen and when component refreshed, the data become an empty array.